# Вопрос о модерации приложений в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Есть ли возможность подать заявку в google play с просьбой, проверить мое приложение на наличие возможных нарушений, которые я мог не выявить в своем приложении самостоятельно для того, чтобы сразу заняться исправлением и во избежания неожиданного блокирования приложения или аккаунта. Куда, я могу обратиться с этой просьбой?

Comment: @Vlad.R, вообще-то не понимаю, каким образом ссылка на связь с гуглом отвечает на конкретный вопрос. Предлагаешь их в чате попросить проверить продукт? Что-то сомнительная идея...

Comment: если у вас обнаружат нарушения, то вам просто откажут в публикации с объяснением причины, сразу блокировать аккаунт не должны